# Resubmit a form after failure in Google Chrome like as in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Firefox if form submission fails  due to reasons like site down etc we can still resubmit the same form and it works.

From this [official site discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2636) I understand Chrome does not retain the form cache on pressing Back button or on failure.

How can I add this functionality using extension?

Comment: Do you seek to write an extension that does that? If yes, which part presents a problem?

Comment: Okay, since you're not looking to write one yourself this is [off-topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Xan sorry .. I intend to write it myself initially and now too.

Comment: Okay: an extension? Code for the webpage itself? Have you tried just pressing "reload", as it will offer to resubmit a POST request? Do you understand that in general, there are many ways a form can function (i.e. POSt vs AJAX POST)? I think it's still too broad.

Comment: @Xan I want to write Extension. On pressing reload it does not work I guess it makes a GET request then.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is, now, "is it possible to make a Chrome extension that saves a form in case something bad happens".

Answer is: Yes for some forms. But a general, 100% reliable approach is not really possible.

Such extensions already exist. However, they don't always work well.

As for architecture, a reasonable approach would be this:

1. Inject a content script in all pages that contain forms you want to track (maybe all of them).
2. Detect forms on the page. Tricky part #1: in our AJAX world, not everything has to be a form to be used as such. I suppose you could just monitor ALL input fields for their values and changes in value, and save the latest version.
3. Detects submissions. Tricky part #2: it can be a form `submit`, or can be some JavaScript doing XHR on its own. `webRequest` API can help but again, in general, it's hard to determine what a "form submission" is. A search from can generate a perfectly reasonable GET request - is that a "form submission"?
4. Restore a form to a pre-submit state. Tricky part #3: his can seriously clash with page's own scripts (for example, for an angular-based page, if you just modify an input's value with JS it will not update the model).